# two bases in one vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space with two bases Q and P. Let T : V → V be a linear transformation with B as its Q-matrix and C as its P-matrix. Prove or disprove each of the following statements.

(a) dim(ker(B)) =dim(ker(C)).

(b) ker(B) =ker(C).

(c) The sum of all entries in B is equal to the sum of all entries in C.

(d) The trace (sum of the diagonal entries) of B is equal to the trace of C.

Hint: It may be useful to remember the fact previously proven on HW #3 that trace(AB)=trace(BA) for any two n×n matrices A and B.

(e) If there exists a vector ⃗v1 such that Bv1 = Kv1 for some scalar k ∈ R, then there exists a vector ⃗v2
such that Cv2 = kv2 for the same value of k.

i dont understand where to start from. do i choose two bases B and C and then assume B of some vector x is equal to zero and then show that of c of x  is also 0. please help me make sense of this. 
TIA!

Comment: Something is wrong with your problem formulation.  A vector space $V$ can have more than one basis, e.g. say $B$ and $C$.  I suspect you mean to say that for linear transformation $T:V\to V$ there is a matrix $M_B$ which represents $T$ with respect to basis $B$, and also a matrix $M_C$ which represents $T$ with respect to basis $C$.  We should use different symbols for the matrices and the bases to avoid confusion.

Comment: yes thats what i meant. ill change it

Comment: You may find it helpful to learn a little about formatting with mathematical expressions.  See this [introduction](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$.